# Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm having some issues with rgrep/find on emacs.  Any search returns 0 results, with this message:

The filename, directory name, or volumn label syntax is incorrect.

Grep finished with no matches found.

I am using the find bundled with cygwin, so I'm curious if me entering d:/workspace is breaking  because find is using cygwin for disk access (so the correct path would be /cygdrive/d/workspace).  However, emacs will balk at /cygdrive/d/workspace as it doesn't read it this way.

I am curious why I am the only one with this problem, when it is common to use cygwin find with emacs.

Different problems now.

When I execute rgrep, I always get the same thing "find: missing argument to `-name`".  Google found nothing on this problem, if I execute grep on it's own.  I don't get the line number links, so I get a report of where the text is found, but I can't click any of them to open that file.

Comment: That error message looks like a standard Windows error message, so I don't think it's picking up the cygwin find.

Comment: It is, windows find will say "FIND: Parameter format not correct".  You are right that it is a windows error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'll have to answer my own here.  I had to use a specially bundled version of emacs for windows (not just the port), to get everything working with grep and find.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of setup, as well as performance, I'd recommend using the native windows version of emacs and the [gnu win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) versions of find and grep etc. The important thing is to make sure that the binaries for these tools are first in your path, before the cygwin ones.

Comment: Notes: It also needs to be before the windows find, not just cygwin.  When I execute rgrep within emacs, it still throws an error.  find: missing argument to `-name`.  The find in gnuwin32 doesn't seem to be compatible with windows port of emacs.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong version of grep, do you have to set 'grep-program' just like you do with 'find-program' in the emacs init file?

Comment: Ok I figured it out ... http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2010/10/rgrep-on-windows-7-for-emacs.html

Comment: I use UnxUtils (http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) with emacs-win32.  Have done so for ...10 years?  Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you are talking about using grep-find, but maybe I am mistaken.)

I agree that part of the problem is passing cygwin's find d:/workspace.  I've never had good luck at mixing cygwin and non-cygwin things together.  Have you considered using the emacs (or XEmacs) builds for cygwin?

When I was mixing things, I ended up setting things up so that a non-cygwin version of emacs knew about cygwin drive names.  I had two different solutions in my .emacs (really .xemacs/init.el) file, one for emacs and one for XEmacs.

```
    ;;
;; Life with Cygwin
;;
(if am-i-running-xemacs-p
    ; true - I am running XEmacs
    (progn
;;--      (setq directory-abbrev-alist
;;--        (append directory-abbrev-alist
;;--                '(("^/cygdrive/a/" . "a:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/b/" . "b:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/c/" . "c:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/d/" . "d:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/e/" . "e:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/f/" . "f:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/g/" . "g:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/h/" . "h:/")
;;--                  ("^/cygdrive/i/" . "i:/")
;;--                  ("^/usr/" .        "d:/cygwin/usr/")
;;--                  ("^/homes/" .      "d:/cygwin/homes/")
;;--                  ("^/etc/" .        "d:/cygwin/etc/")
;;--                  ("^/lib/" .        "d:/cygwin/lib/")
;;--                  ("^/var/" .        "d:/cygwin/var/")
;;--                  ("^/include/" .    "d:/cygwin/include/")
;;--                  ("^/info/" .       "d:/cygwin/info/")
;;-                   ("^/" . "c:\\"))
;;--                ))
            )
      )
    ; false (else) - I am Not running XEmacs
    (progn
       (require 'cygwin32-mount)

       ;; make cygwin symlinks accessible
       (defun follow-cygwin-symlink ()
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char 0)
           (if (looking-at "!<symlink>")
               (progn
                 (re-search-forward "!<symlink>\\(.*\\)\0")
                 (find-alternate-file (match-string 1)))
             )))
       (add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'follow-cygwin-symlink)
))
```

I no longer use these as once I get into cygwin, I stay in cygwin (i.e. cygwin emacs, cygwin find).

- John

Comment: I figured sticking to the windows port was safer than relying on the cygwin team to port emacs, but this is a pretty big oversight by emacs.  Thank you very much for providing this script.  Have you tried using a port of find maybe from gnuwin32?

Comment: I pretty much stick to using the cygwin packages at this point, so I can't comment on the gnuwin32 find.